# jquery scroll events fire in delay when the page completed loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, prestashop

I'm creating a theme for prestashop 1.7, but I don't really think that relates to the issue i'm having. (`update`: i think it may relate to how prestashop operates because as a stand-alone it works properly)

prestashop 1.7 comes with jquery 2.2.4.

I want to a have a floating cart icon for the user that will stick to the left:0 top:50%, and when the user scrolls the page to will animate it's re-position.

so I have this initial css for my floating cart:

```
div#floating_cart {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 1%;
}
```

and this is the javascript code to catch the scroll:

```
   $(window).scroll(function () {
        $('#floating_cart').animate({top:Math.floor($(window).scrollTop() +(window.innerHeight/2))},100,"swing");
    });
```

the problem is  that after the page loads and i try to scroll, only after 4-5 seconds the cart starts all the re-positioning animation it has in his stack.

any ideas how to resolve this delay ?

## update

if I only set `position:fixed`, the cart stays at the chosen position without any problems. but I want it to animate a bit.

so I tried using the following code:

```
$(function() {

    $(window).on("load", function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            $('#floating_cart').css('position', 'absolute');
            $('#floating_cart').stop();
            $('#floating_cart').animate({top: Math.floor($(window).scrollTop() + (window.innerHeight / 2))}, 300, "swing");
        });
    }); 
});
```

and the results are exactly the same.

so I changed the css of floating cart:

```
div#floating_cart {
  position: fixed;
  top: 49%;
  left: 1%;
}
```

and I add a 8 seconds delay before attaching to the scroll, and setting the position to `absolute` instead of `fixed`.

```
$(function() {

    $(window).on("load", function () {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                $('#floating_cart').css('position', 'absolute');
                $('#floating_cart').stop();
                $('#floating_cart').animate({top: Math.floor($(window).scrollTop() + (window.innerHeight / 2))}, 300, "swing");
            });
        },8000);

    });
});
```

now I'm thinking it may relate to how prestashop loads stuff.
how can I investigate this issue further? code is compressed when I load the page so it's hard to debug

Comment: And at what point are you attaching that scroll handler to the window object ...?

Comment: @CBroe - updating main post

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not working because you don’t have all the ressources avaible when the page is loading. Try to check if the inclusion of jquery isn’t with the `async` attribute.

You can also record the scripts when the page is loading via the web ressource inspector in most web browsers

Comment: thank you for your answer. is there a way to detect when all the resources finished loading ? jquery onready function is not enough. i'll just set the position to fixed and when the resources has finished loading i'll change it to absolute